# Из активити не обновляется RecyclerView во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

При нажатии кнопки меню в MainActivity обновляются данные, изпользуемые в RecyclerView. Сам рецайклер сидит во фрагменте, пытаюсь сообщить ему, что данные изменились, примерно так:

```
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout);    
RecyclerView rv =(RecyclerView)f.getView().findViewById(R.id.RVNick);    
rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

В результате ничего не меняется. Хотя вызов .notifyDataSetChanged() из самого фрагмента отлично всё обновляет. Пробовал также сделать рецайклер public static и обратиться напрямую, тоже не выходит. Что я делаю не так? Как правильно обновить Recycler? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Каким образом обновляются данные в адаптере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем представляю как  у вас реализован фрагмент и активити. Но допустим у вас есть активити в ней фрагмент не на весь экран, а кнопка находится именно в активити. Вы можете сделать это примерно так.

В адаптере создаете метод

```
public void replaceItems() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

После чего так же создаете интерфейс примерно так:

```
interface IFragmentController {

    void updateAdapter();

}
```

В активити создаете экземпляр интерфейса:

```
private IFragmentController mFragmentController;

//some code

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 mFragmentController = (IFragmentController) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container); 
                 mFragmentController.updateAdapter();
            }
        });
```

Далее во фрагменте вам необходимо реализовать этот интерфейс

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements IFragmentController{

//some code

@Override
    public void updateAdapter() {
        if(adapter!=null){
             adapter.replaceItem();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Сделал всё, как Вы написали, реакция ровно такая же, как и была, - данные не обновляются. Наверное, я не совсем точно описал проблему. В основной активити есть меню, всё остальное - контейнер фрагмента. В контейнере фрагмент с рецайклером (сразу при старте активити). Я не могу обновить данные именно при нажатии кнопки меню, обрабатываемом в  .onOptionsItemSelected. Если плюхнуть кнопку рядом с контейнером фрагмента и обработать в ней - проблем никаких нет. А из меню почему-то не выходит. Кстати, из фрагмента в обработчике  .onOptionsItemSelected рецайклер тоже не обновляется.

Comment: Значит проблема где-то в меню. Пришлите весь код активити и фрагмента

Comment: Хотел воспроизвести проблему в новом пустом проекте, чтобы не слать много кода. Но там всё работает ) В итоге нашел свой косяк в коде фрагмента, вопрос решен. Спасибо за помощь!